# jQuery reversing the direction of an effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#left_image1").delay('1000').animate({width:'toggle'}, 1000);
```

This causes the element to collapse in such a way that it appears to be moving off the LEFT side of the screen. How can I reverse the effect so that the element appears to be moving off the right side of the screen?

Comment: I think if you just use the same code again, it will give you the reverse effect. Try this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/tariqulazam/Tsbuw/ and let me know.

Comment: No, I do not want the element to be brought back from the right, rather I want another element to slide off to the right.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/Tsbuw/1/

Comment: Please post more code in your question (HTML, CSS) so somebody can post a more complete answer.  Right now it's all guessing about what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not quite so simple. The reason it appears to be going to the left is because you element is left aligned. If it was right aligned it would appear to go to the right. You could fix this in a variety of ways, but since you didn't post your html/css I can't give a specific answer. One way you could go about this is by floating your html element to the right, or by absolutely positioning the element to the right of its container element.